# Terraform nested dynamic blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I'm trying to deploy an Azure application gateway in Terraform, in particular I need to create a nested dynamic blocks.

I have tried to implement this (this part of the code is in a file called application_gateway.tf):

```
  dynamic "url_path_map" {
    for_each = var.path_maps
    content {
      name                               = outer_block.value["name"]
      default_backend_address_pool_name  = outer_block.value["backend"]
      default_backend_http_settings_name = outer_block.value["backend_set"]
      dynamic "url_path_rule" {
        for_each = url_path_map.value["upm"]
        content{
          name                       = url_path_rule.value["name_rule"]
          paths                      = url_path_rule.value["path"]
          backend_address_pool_name  = url_path_rule.value["backend"]
          backend_http_settings_name = url_path_rule.value["backend_set"]
        } 
      }
    } 
  }
```

The correspective variables.tf file is:

```
variable "path_maps" {
  default = []
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    backend = string
    backend_set = string
    upm = list(object({
      name_rule = string
      path = string
      backend = string
      backend_set = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

With the following module call (this part of the script is in another file called main.tf):

```
module "application_gateway" {
  source = "../modules/resources-hub/application_gateway"

  resource_group_name        = module.resource_group.name
  resource_group_location    = module.resource_group.location
  subnet_id                  = module.agw_subnet.id
  public_ip_address_id       = module.app_gw_pip.id
  firewall_policy_id         = module.agw_web_application_firewall.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = module.log_analytics_workspace.id



  path_maps = [{name = "dev_url_path_name", backend = "devBackend", backend_set = "devHttpSetting", name_rule = "dev_path_rule_name_app", path = "/app/*"},
               {name = "tst_url_path_name", backend = "tstBackend", backend_set = "tstHttpSetting", name_rule = "dev_path_rule_name_edp", path = "/edp/*"},
               {name = "uat_url_path_name", backend = "uatBackend", backend_set = "uatHttpSetting", name_rule = "dev_path_rule_name_internal", path = "/internal/*"}]
}
```

At the end, what I would like to obtain is this but using the nested dynamic blocks:

```
  url_path_map {
    name      = "dev_url_path_name"
    default_backend_address_pool_name = "devBackend"
    default_backend_http_settings_name = "devHttpSetting"
      path_rule {
        name = "dev_path_rule_name_app_edp"
        paths = ["/app/*"]
        backend_address_pool_name = "devBackend"
        backend_http_settings_name = "devHttpSetting"
      }
      path_rule {
        name = "dev_path_rule_name_internal"
        paths = ["/edp/*"]
        backend_address_pool_name = "devBackend"
        backend_http_settings_name = "devHttpSetting"
      }
      path_rule {
        name = "dev_path_rule_name_internal"
        paths = ["/internal/*"]
        backend_address_pool_name = "sinkPool"
        backend_http_settings_name = "devHttpSetting"
      }
  }
```

This is the error that I get if I run "terraform validate":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Trk.png)

Thank you in advance!

I have tried the code above but I got the error in the image.

Comment: Please add the error as text, not a screenshot. But, based on the error, you are setting the `upm` parameter as required in the variable definition and you are not providing it in the variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is on the definition of the variable "path_maps", because is different as the path_maps format that you are passing to the module.

You can modify the path_maps before passing to the module with the correct format, or you can change variable to fit the format that you define.

thats why you are getting the error that "upm" is required